# Value for header {Authorization: Token : } must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token'>

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to learn pytest with Django for testing. I have been able to successfully send get requests using requests.get method. Now I am trying to send a post request which requires authentication which is where I am struggling:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
class testAllAPIEndPoints(TestCase):
    def test_authenticated(self):
        self.user = AdminFactory.create(username="superadmin", 
        password="argon2$argon2id$v=19$m=102400,t=2,p=8$ODFhSWlQTzk4R1kyZ25odFpRcEZRZA$Pq45GNeM0Lab5e5gh9hTFfxswAqfWovllyYkoWyPARo",
        email = "rebelbodycollective@gmail.com", is_superuser = True, is_active= True
        ) 
        # self.user =  User.objects.get(username="superadmin")
        print("----------------------- LOG ------------------------------------------")
        # This is returnin True
       
        print(self.user.email)
        self.token = Token.objects.create(user= self.user)


        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        # self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=self.user.password)
        print(self.user.is_authenticated ) 
        print(self.token)
        # url = reverse("admin:users_user_add")
        # self.client.login(username="superadmin", password="t;At\"WF5%>p>V][b!@_V&Ksb\'L^\\n:*}")
        # self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = "Token " + self.token)
        user = UserFactory()

        inst = InstructorFactory.build(user=user)

        # print("REVERSE URL")
        # url = reverse("instructor:users_user_add")
        # print(url)
        # print("REVERSE URL")
        print("FIRST NAME: " + inst.firstName)
        print("last NAME: " + inst.lastName)

        

        # print("tags" + inst.tags)
        data = dict(
                        isActive='on',
                        user = inst.user.id,
                        # tags = 1, not required
                        firstName = inst.firstName,
                        lastName = inst.lastName,
                        username = "superadmin",
                        password = "argon2$argon2id$v=19$m=102400,t=2,p=8$ODFhSWlQTzk4R1kyZ25odFpRcEZRZA$Pq45GNeM0Lab5e5gh9hTFfxswAqfWovllyYkoWyPARo",
                        phone = inst.phone,
                        bio = inst.bio,
                        tags = "abc",
                        website = inst.website,
                        _save = 'Save'
                      )

        # 302: Redirect for undefined reason. 
        # Clients making subsequent requests for this resource should not use the new URI. 
        # Clients should not follow the redirect automatically for POST/PUT/DELETE requests.
        
        # response =self.client.get('http://localhost:8000/')

        response =requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/instructors/', json = data, headers={'Authorization: Token ':self.token})
        print(response.content)
        
        # FIX ME
        
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have tried various methods but keep on hitting road blocks. With this test I am getting the error:

> E           requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Value for header
> {Authorization: Token : 7e3b12cd3729d990eb2b2e2bb50c89407d61ae90} must
> be of type str or bytes, not <class
> 'rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token'>

I have tried to look online but the it has not been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to source https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py You can get the string from the token instance by calling `__str__()` or maybe just simply getting the key field

```py
response =requests.post(
   'http://localhost:8000/api/instructors/', 
   json = data, 
   headers={'Authorization: Token ':self.token.key})
```